# как получить значение из полии html в aiohttp?

Tags: python, aiohttp

как получить значение из полии  html в aiohttp?

Comment: Можете уточнить что такое полия?

Comment: на пример элемент input в форме :<input type="text" name="user" id="user"?

Answer (score 1):

Пример из [документации](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/web_quickstart.html#http-forms):

```
async def do_login(request):
    data = await request.post()
    username = data['user']
```

Comment: А вот здесь точно пробел должен быть? `await request`

Comment: @Andrey вы можете перейти по ссылке и убедится в этом.